# Why can xgboost not deal with this simple Chinese sentence case?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, random-forest, decision-tree, xgboost

There is only 1 feature dim. But the result is unreasonable. The code and data is below. The purpose of the code is to judge whether the two sentences are the same.

**In fact, the final input to the model is: feature is [1] with label 1, and feature is [0] with label 0.**

The data is quite simple:

---

sent1 sent2 label

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

我想听 我想听 1

我想听 我想说 0

我想说 我想说 1

我想说 我想听 0

---

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
d = pd.read_csv("data_small.tsv",sep=" ")


def my_test(sent1,sent2):
    result = [0]
    if "我想说" in sent1 and "我想说" in sent2:
        result[0] = 1
    if "我想听" in sent1 and "我想听" in sent2:
        result[0] = 1
    return result

fea_ = d.apply(lambda row: my_test(row['sent1'], row['sent2']), axis=1).tolist()

labels = d["label"].tolist()
fea = pd.DataFrame(fea_)
for i in range(len(fea_)):
    print(fea_[i],labels[i])

labels = pd.DataFrame(labels)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# train_x_pd_split, valid_x_pd, train_y_pd_split, valid_y_pd = train_test_split(fea, labels, test_size=0.2,
#                                                                                random_state=1234)

train_x_pd_split = fea[0:16]
valid_x_pd = fea[16:20]
train_y_pd_split = labels[0:16]
valid_y_pd = labels[16:20]


train_xgb_split = xgb.DMatrix(train_x_pd_split, label=train_y_pd_split)
valid_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(valid_x_pd, label=valid_y_pd)
watch_list = [(train_xgb_split, 'train'), (valid_xgb, 'valid')]


params3 = {
    'seed': 1337,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.48,
    'silent': 1,
    'subsample': 1,
    'eta': 0.05,
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'eval_metric': 'logloss',
    'max_depth': 8,
    'min_child_weight': 20,
    'nthread': 8,
    'tree_method': 'hist',
}

xgb_trained_model = xgb.train(params3, train_xgb_split, 1000, watch_list, early_stopping_rounds=50,
                              verbose_eval=10)
# xgb_trained_model.save_model("predict/model/xgb_model_all")
print("feature importance 0:")
importance = xgb_trained_model.get_fscore()
temp1 = []
temp2 = []

for k in importance:
    temp1.append(k)
    temp2.append(importance[k])

print("-----")
feature_importance_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column': temp1,
    'importance': temp2,
}).sort_values(by='importance')

# print(feature_importance_df)

feature_sort_list = feature_importance_df["column"].tolist()
feature_importance_list = feature_importance_df["importance"].tolist()
print()
for i,item in enumerate(feature_sort_list):
    print(item,feature_importance_list[i])


train_x_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(train_x_pd_split)
train_predict = xgb_trained_model.predict(train_x_xgb)

print(train_predict)

train_predict_binary = (train_predict >= 0.5) * 1
print("TRAIN DATA SELF")
from sklearn import metrics
print('LogLoss: %.4f' % metrics.log_loss(train_y_pd_split, train_predict))
print('AUC: %.4f' % metrics.roc_auc_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict))
print('ACC: %.4f' % metrics.accuracy_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))
print('Recall: %.4f' % metrics.recall_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))
print('F1-score: %.4f' % metrics.f1_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))
print('Precesion: %.4f' % metrics.precision_score(train_y_pd_split, train_predict_binary))

print()
valid_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(valid_x_pd)
valid_predict = xgb_trained_model.predict(valid_xgb)

print(valid_predict)

valid_predict_binary = (valid_predict >= 0.5) * 1
print("TEST DATA PERFORMANCE")
from sklearn import metrics
print('LogLoss: %.4f' % metrics.log_loss(valid_y_pd, valid_predict))
print('AUC: %.4f' % metrics.roc_auc_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict))
print('ACC: %.4f' % metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
print('Recall: %.4f' % metrics.recall_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
print('F1-score: %.4f' % metrics.f1_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
print('Precesion: %.4f' % metrics.precision_score(valid_y_pd, valid_predict_binary))
```

But result shows that xgboost do not fit the data:

```
TRAIN DATA SELF
LogLoss: 0.6931
AUC: 0.5000
ACC: 0.5000
Recall: 1.0000
F1-score: 0.6667
Precesion: 0.5000

TEST DATA PERFORMANCE
LogLoss: 0.6931
AUC: 0.5000
ACC: 0.5000
Recall: 1.0000
F1-score: 0.6667
Precesion: 0.5000
```

Comment: Assuming it's an algorithmic rather than a straight-up programming issue, migrate to [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Question belongs on [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is identical to XOR, which, though simply stated, is a notoriously hard problem in machine learning.

Comment: wtf r u guys talking about?? xgboost solves XOR easy! and it is NOT HARD problem in machine learning! It's only impossible for LINEAR classifiers. Though it's new to me xgboost deals with strings rather than numerics.

Comment: EranMoshe is right, @Scott. XOR is not exactly "notoriously hard", it just forces a maximum-depth tree, so for 2^N cases you simply get a depth-N (balanced) tree. XOR is only hard/impossible for linear classifiers.

Comment: I never said that XOR was impossible.  XOR is literally a textbook example of an ML problem that does not have a simple solution, i.e. is hard.   Also, just because there exists a depth-2 tree that solves XOR does not imply that decision-tree algorithms tend to find it (they don't search the whole tree space).  Indeed, if one tries to make an initial decision on any given variable, then for balanced data NO single decision decreases the entropy of the problem.  This at least implies that special care must be taken (e.g. enforcing some kind of "balance" metric).

Comment: Either way, I recind my guess that xgboost is bad at XOR if y'all say otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtained 100% converge. Here are differences between the configurations:

1. I set `min_child_weight` to 0. It’s unreasonable to set it to 20 and expect XGBoost to find split.
2. I removed `colsample_bytree`, you only have 1 features, I don’t think sampling is a good choice.